# Embed Instagram feed in blog header

Tags: embed, instagram

I would like to Embed my Instagram feed in my blog header.

I can embed in header but my pictures show below each others instead of next to each other. Do you have a tip or a plugin that does this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Instansive](http://instansive.com). There you can setup number of rows, columns and other stuff.